# HELP Transfer large file from Home PC to Virtual Dedicated Server!

Tags: windows

I have a virtual dedicated server running windows server 2003. My home computer runs Vista business. I can easily connect via remote desktop or ftp to my virtual dedicated server. The problem is I have a 6 GB File that I'm trying to transfer from my home pc to my virtual dedicated server. I tried through ftp and everything was going well, I was 60% through after waiting a full day, and it timed out. I also tried splitting the file into multiple files but each file is still at least a GB which takes at least an hour. Is there any solution for quicker file transfers?

Comment: Can you compress the file?

Comment: It's 6 GB when compressed into zip format

Answer (score 1):

If you're transferring via ftp (with for example filezilla) and it times out you can resume the transfer and continue from where you left

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the file into smaller ones was the solution I think. FTP normally is a fast way to transfer files.

The Problem is that your connection seems to be very slow. I've heard from some hosting companies where you can send files e.g. on a USB Stick or a mobile hard drive an they plug it into your server. When your company doesn't you can search for a better connection maybe on a internet coffee or at an friend's home.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a combination of breaking the file up, FTP resume (not sure how well that will work) and going somewhere with a faster upload speed.  If you have access to a local college or University, that might help.  A public library could help as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use Binfer to regularly move backup data from CentOS to my home PC. I have gnome running on the CentOS. Binfer is java based and its real easy. no need to mess around with FTP. Check it out: http://www.binfer.com